# SPI and pullups. Is it ever used in open collector configuration

Tags: spi, pullup, open-collector

Is SPI ever wired as open collector in devices calling for the use of pullup resistors? Everything seems to point to it usually being totem pole but I wonder if there are exceptions.

The only pullup really required seems to be on the chip select, but sometimes a pullup on MISO seems to be used also for reliability/robustness reasons.

Can someone describe minimal pullup/pulldown requirements for SPI buses, and answer if totem pole configuration is the standardized driving method for SPI?

Comment: I've never needed to use pulls on any of the data lines, but I do often use a weak pullup on the chip select line to ensure that a peripheral isn't listening if the microcontroller goes into a weird state or during initializaion. This is especially true if the SPI lines are used for something else, like a programmer interface. In this case, it's been recommended to put 330R in line to isolate the programmer signals from any peripherals.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as I know, SPI lines are always actively driven in both directions.

I sometimes put a pulldown on the MISO line because it could be floating for extended periods of time.  Only the slave with slave select asserted is allowed to drive the line, so when no slave is selected, the line floats.

Floating MISO doesn't cause any data problems because it only floats when its value is meaningless and the master shouldn't be looking at the line anyway.  However, intermediate voltages on some digital inputs can cause trouble.  They can cause oscillations and higher than specified current draw inside the receiving chip.  A weak, even 100 kΩ, pulldown keeps the line at the logic low level when not in use.

I usually use a pulldown, but you can use a pullup just as well.  This only sets the line's data value when not in use, so you can pick either.  To me it seems more intuitive to have the line say "0" when not in use, but this is really totally arbitrary.  If you might fully power down some slaves when the SPI bus is not in use, then it should be a pulldown.

Answer (score 6):

> sometimes a pullup on MISO seems to be used

This is done mostly on SD cards, because they come out of reset as open drain and must be switched into SPI with a command. You would also need a pullup/down when the slave may be disconnected somehow to put the non-driven line to a known state.

> if totem pole configuration is the standardized driving method for SPI

SPI is always push-pull, because this yields fastest signal rise and fall times.

The mentioned SD card as an example has maximum clock rate of 400 kHz in open drain mode initially, but 25 MHz when configured as SPI.